# What parameters should I use in a Google Maps URL to go to a lat-lon?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-urls

I would like to produce a url for Google Maps that goes to a specific latitude and longitude. Now, I generate a url such as this:

[http://maps.google.com/maps?z=11&t=k&q=58 41.881N 152 31.324W](http://maps.google.com/maps?z=11&t=k&q=58%2041.881N%20152%2031.324W)

The resulting map comes up with a round "A" balloon pointer, which seems to point to the nearest named object, and a green arrow, which points to the lat-lon. Sometimes, as in this example, the "A" pointer is centered and is far enough away that you cannot see the pointer to the lat-lon. (Zoom out to see both pointers in this example. The "A" pointer is in the center of Alaska, while the lat-long pointer is on Kodiak Island.)

Are there some parameters I can use in the Google Maps URL that will produce a single pointer to a designated lat-lon? (This loads in a separate window. It is not embedded.)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In May 2017 Google announced the **Google Maps URLs** API that allows to construct universal cross-platform links. Now you can open Google maps on web, Android or iOS using the same URL string in form:

`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&parameters`

There are several modes that you can use: search, directions, show map and show street view.

So you can use something like

`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=58.698017,-152.522067`

to open map and place marker on some lat and lng.

For further details please refer to:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

With zoom (z: 1 to 20) you can use this:

`https://maps.google.com/?q=38.6531004,-90.243462&ll=38.6531004,-90.243462&z=3`

Answer (score 265):

This is current accepted way to link to a specific lat lon (rather than search for the nearest object).

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:38.9419+-78.3020
```

- `z` is the zoom level (1-20)
- `t` is the map type ("m" map, "k" satellite, "h" hybrid, "p" terrain, "e" GoogleEarth)
- `q` is the search query, if it is prefixed by `loc:` then google assumes it is a lat lon separated by a `+`

Comment: Thank you! 'loc:' was the key for me, as just a lat long puts a green pin at the lat/long and then a red pin at the nearest search result.

Comment: FYI, a recent change to google maps means that the `loc` parameter no-longer seems to work as it did. You need to add an `@` symbol - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939725/why-has-google-maps-q-parameter-stopped-working

Comment: `t=k` the way to go for Satellite / current Earth!

Comment: How to make your url zoom parameter work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806084/google-map-zoom-parameter-in-url-not-working/32807681#32807681

Comment: Is it possible to add more than one marker to an app? And if it works, how does the structure looks like?

Comment: Is there any way to include options like "Avoid Highways" or Tolls etc using the URL. I know how to do that using the Intent but I want to use that in the URL.

Answer (score 105):

yeah I had the same question for a long time and I found the perfect one. here are some parameters from it.

```
https://maps.google.com?parameter = value
```

**q=**

is used to specify the search query in Google maps search.
eg :

```
https://maps.google.com?q=newyork or
https://maps.google.com?q=51.03841,-114.01679
```

**near=**

is used to specify the location alternative to `q=`. Also has the added effect of allowing you to increase the AddressDetails Accuracy value by being more precise. Mostly only useful if query is a **business** or suchlike.

**z=**

Zoom level. Can be set 19 normally, but in certain cases can go up to 23.

> **ll=**
>
> Latitude and longitude of the map centre point. Must be in that order.
>   Requires decimal format. Interestingly, you can use this without q, in
>   which case it doesn’t show a marker.

**sll=**

Similar to ll, only this sets the lat/long of the centre point for a business search. Requires the same input criteria as ll.

**t=**

Sets the kind of map shown. Can be set to:

```
m – normal  map,
k – satellite,
h – hybrid,
p – terrain
```

**saddr=**

Sets the starting point for directions searches. You can also add text into this in brackets to bold it in the directions sidebar.

**daddr=**

Sets the end point for directions searches, and again will bold any text added in brackets.You can also add "+to:" which will set via points. These can be added multiple times.

**via=**

Allows you to insert via points in directions. Must be in CSV format. For example, via=1,5 addresses 1 and 5 will be via points without entries in the sidebar. The start point (which is set as 0), and 2, 3 and 4 will all show full addresses.

**doflg=**

Changes the units used to measure distance (will default to the standard unit in country of origin). Change to **ptk** for metric or **ptm** for imperial.

**msa=**

Does stuff with My Maps. Set to 0 show defined My Maps, b to turn the My Maps sidebar on, 1 to show the My Maps tab on its own, or 2 to go to the new My Map creator form.

**dirflg=**

can set miscellaneous values below:

```
h - Avoid highway
t - Avoid tolls
```

**reference**
http://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

Comment: @SameeraR. Is there any way to include "Avoid Highways, Tolls" etc option using these URLs?

Comment: there is a parameter called dirflg. dirflg=h (Avoid highways),
dirflg=t (Avoid tolls). I'll include this in the answer too.

Comment: [**Docs**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme) says that  `@` in `https://maps.google.com?q=@51.03841,-114.01679` - should work. but it doesn't. Any idea why ?

Comment: did you try adding '/' before '?' like this 
https://maps.google.com/?q=@37.3161,-122.1836

Answer (score 38):

This should help with the new Google Maps:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/place/<name>/@<lat>,<long>,15z/data=<mode-value>
```

- The `place` adds a marker.
- `name` could be a search term like "realtors"/"lawyers".
- `lat` and `long` are the coordinates in decimal format and in that order.
- `15z` sets zoom level to 15 (must be between 1 ~ 20).
- You can enforce a particular view mode (map is default) - earth or terrain by adding these:

  - *Terrain*: `/data=!5m1!1e4`
  - *Earth*: `/data=!3m1!1e3`

E.g.: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Lawyer/@48.8187768,2.3792362,15z/data=!3m1!1e3

**References:**
https://moz.com/blog/new-google-maps-url-parameters
http://dddavemaps.blogspot.in/2015/07/google-maps-url-tricks.html

Comment: It would be nice to see how to make the map default to a terrain or hybrid view.

Comment: @ThomasValadez - I have edited my answer highlighting the same.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid Highways and tolls using the URL?

Comment: also, for satellite map - /data=!3m1!1e3

Answer (score 12):

The following works as of April 2014.  Delimiting each component of the URL with `+` and `&` for spaces and addition statements, respectively.

Full HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Scottish+Rite+Hamilton+ON&loc:43.25911+-79.879494&z=15&output=embed"></iframe>
```

Broken down:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=
```

where ?q= starts the general search, which I provide a venue, city, province info using `+` for spaces.

```
Scottish+Rite+Hamilton+ON
```

Next the geo-data.  Lat and lng.

```
&loc:43.25911+-79.879494
```

Zoom level

```
&z=15
```

Required for iframes:

```
&output=embed
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this information. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The zoom level parameter doesn't seem to make any difference, has this param changed? E.G compare http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Scottish+Rite+Hamilton+ON&loc:43.25911+-79.879494&z=15
 and 
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Scottish+Rite+Hamilton+ON&loc:43.25911+-79.879494&z=1

Comment: When I've tried using q and loc together the q is used and the loc parameter is ignored.

Comment: @Dave Barnett if you are still on the site can you give an updated version because its not working for me

Answer (score 11):

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=58%2041.881N%20152%2031.324W
```

Just use the coordinates as `q`-parameter. Strip the `z` and `t` prameters. While `z` should actually just be the zoom level, it seems that it won't work if you set any.

`t` is the map type. Having that said, it's not obvious how those parameters would affect the result in the shown way. But they do.

Maybe you should try the `ll`-parameter, but only decimal format will be accepted.

You can find a quick overview of all the parameters [here](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters).

Comment: Your link pointed to the best answer - put "loc:" after "q=", as in   http://maps.google.com/maps?z=11&t=k&q=loc:58 41.881N 152 31.324W

Comment: Cool thing, didn't know of this one. I would have created a custom marker, but this seems easier :)

Comment: How can we avoid highways and tolls using the URL?

Answer (score 9):

If you need a name on your pin, you can also use:

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=MY%20LOCATION@lat,long
```

Comment: Unfortunately the pin name doesn't work if we replace the lat,long with an address. :(

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with the new Google Maps :(

Answer (score 9):

All the answers didn't work for me (the loc: and @ options). So here is my solution for the new Google maps (April 2014)

Use the q= for query description, for example the street or the name of the place. 
Use ll= for the lat, long coordinates.

You can add extra parameters like t=h (hybrid) and z=19 (zoom)

https://maps.google.com/?q=11+wall+street+new+york&ll=40.7060471,-74.0088901

https://maps.google.com/?q=new+york+stock+exchange&ll=40.7060471,-74.0088901

https://maps.google.com/?q=new+york+stock+exchange&ll=40.7060471,-74.0088901&t=h&z=19

Answer (score 9):

There have been a number of changes, some incompatible, since I asked this question 5 years ago. Currently, the following works properly:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/58°41.881N 152°31.324W/@58.698017,-152.522067,12z/
```

The first latitude/longitude will be used for the pin location and label. It can be in degrees-minutes-seconds, degrees-minutes, or degrees. The second latitude/longitude (following the "@") is the map center. It must be in degrees only in order for the zoom (12z) to be recognized.

For terrain view, you can append "data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0!5m1!1e4". I can find no documentation on this, though, so the spec could change.

Answer (score 6):

New Version queries have a different format

To reach a lat long by url use (e.g.)

https://www.google.com/maps/search/-15.924,-5.719

Answer (score 4):

works fine
https://maps.google.de/maps?q=51.404989,13.091751&z=17&t=k

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have to be much more complicated than passing in a value for the 'q' parameter. Google is a *search engine* after all and can handle the same stuff it handles when users type queries into its text boxes

```
"maps.google.com?/q=32.5234,-78.23432"
```

Comment: You are correct. Google has changed to center the map on the coordinates instead of the nearest major object. The example in the original question works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

This works to zoom into an area more then drop a pin:
https://www.google.com/maps/@30.2,17.9820525,9z

And the params are:

```
@lat,lng,zoom
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have degrees minutes seconds you can pass them on the url :

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=latDegrees latMinutes latSeconds longDegrees longMinutes longSeconds
```

substitute in %20 for the spaces

Answer (score -1):

"ll" worked best for me, see:

http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters (query reference)

it shall not be too hard to convert minutes, seconds to decimal

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

for a marker, possibly the best would be ?q=Description@lat,long

Comment: things change over time, especially for agile teams like Google. History of internet is one of problems. I would not expect that answer which perhaps was a solution in 2012 will still hold in 2014, 2017 or later... Sorry about that. Stack Overflow is full of historic quotes to things that do not exist any more.