# How to get a url for the current location in Mapkit?

Tags: xcode, mapkit, ios5

I have a view controller which loads a  map, I have set the current location as default when the map loads, the question I have is, how do I get a url for this location, so that I can store it in a nsstring and use it at some other place, to add it to tweet sheet basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create an URL such as https://maps.google.com/maps??ll=55.123,12.234

Get the users coordinates from the MKMapView current users location

```
mapView.userLocation.coordinate
```

or if it's the current map center you are interested in

```
mapView.centerCoordinate
```

In practice it would look like this

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoord = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?ll=%f,%f",
                                                  myCoord.latitude,
                                                  myCoord.longitude];

NSLog(@"The URL is: %@", url);
```

The snippet gives me the following output:

The URL is: http://maps.google.com/?ll=55.936699,12.289743

The parameters for the Google Maps URL can be found through [Google](http://querystring.org/google-maps-query-string-parameters/) and has been dealt with on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201).

Comment: Thanks for the answer,that would mean I would have to replace the values in the url every time?I'm new to xcode so if that sounds foolish bear with me.I tried using a clmapcordinate2d *mycord and assigning the latt and long values as you said to *mycord.But then how do I set the url to take mycord instead of the actual values.Is it possible to set q=mycord?

Comment: I updated the answer to show the creation of the string as well - I also switched to using the ll parameter to Google Maps. Let me know if you need a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thats awesome man, this helped me a lot, but still there is one problem, the nslog output is not taking the coordinates of my current location, its taking 0,0 as the coordinate values? I have setshowuserlocation set to yes, so my coord should take the values of the current location coordinate right?

Comment: Depending on where you are calling the code it might be zero for the first couple of seconds until a location is established. If you are using the simulator you have to specify a "fake" location from the menus of the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

you must save the city and county in a string. 
then you can build a google link like this:

```
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@,%@",city,country"];
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply, but isn't there a way to fill in the  city and country parameters automatically when the users current location is loaded,otherwise it will be kind of impractical for users in different areas.