# Is there a way to construct mobile friendly google maps urls that do not redirect to google places?

Tags: google-maps

I'm attempting to construct and send a google maps url to a mobile browser. When the url is opened I would like it to bring up a google map with the geopoint marked. I have seen the stack question: [What parameters should I use in a Google Maps URL to go to a lat-lon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon) And the answer there works perfectly for iphones, and standard PC/Mac browsers. However I opened the link I created

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?z=18&t=h&q=loc:51.5+-0.07
```

with Opera Mobile and was redirected to google places with a url like

```
maps.google.com/m/local?z=18&t=h&q=loc:51.5+-0.07
```

and the textbox was filled with

```
loc:51.5 -0.07
```

i.e. the geopoint. There was no map in sight, and searching for the details autofilled in the text box did not give me anything. When I attempted to navigate to this url on my mac it gave me a 404 error. Is there a way to construct mobile friendly google maps urls that will not redirect to google places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters for launching Google Maps are undocumented, which means they're subject to change without notification. You might want to look at using a Google Maps API instead, such as the Static Maps API if all you want is an image:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/
or the JavaScript API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

That way too you can keep people in your own application.

Comment: Thanks Mano, this is what I ended up doing. It's not an ideal solution, but it works :)