# Create a circle around a location by GET parameters only

Tags: google-maps, url

I need to generate a link to Google Maps, containing a location and a circle around it. I found several questions/answers related on generating URLs (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon)).
I'm able to display a location, use zoom factors, etc. so far (see link below).

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=39.211374,-82.978277+%28You+Were+Here%29&z=14&ll=39.211374,-82.978277
```

[(clickable)](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=39.211374,-82.978277%20%28You%20Were%20Here%29&z=14&ll=39.211374,-82.978277)

But is it possible to add a circle with a certain radius arount the specified location? (I know it is with javascript but this is not an option).

On a related note: is there a description of all the GET parameters available? Many answers link to http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters, which is not available anymore.

Comment: What's the intention? Share a generated link?

Comment: @HugoLemos Yes, save the links and be able to share it...

Comment: Have you tried Static Maps and path? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: @HugoLemos No, I didn't know this exists. But it looks promising at a first glance.

Comment: @rob,  http://alvarestech.com/temp/routeconverter/RouteConverter/navigation-formats/src/main/doc/googlemaps/Google_Map_Parameters.htm is an alternative link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of research I think i can say that it is not possible to draw a circle around a location as is possible with the JavaScript API.
It is, however, possible to draw a polygon around a location and since a circle can (almost) be modeled as a polygon this is a possible solution to the problem.
A possible implementation in PHP is described [here](http://jomacinc.com/map-radius/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is it:

```
circle = new google.maps.Circle({

map: map,
radius: XXX,
position: xxxx,
visible: boolean
})

marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions); 
// binds radius(circle) to marker
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```