# Apple Maps URL Scheme t=

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-maps

I'm trying to set the map type in the URL using Apple Maps but it doens't seem to be working. 
What could I do differently? I do this by specifying the type as `&t=satellite` in the URL, like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=%@,%@&t=satellite", LatitudeCurrentLocation, LongitudeCurrentLocation]]];
```

Latitude and longitude are NSStrings that contains the latitude and longitude coordinates.

How can I set the may type in the URL?

Comment: If you remove the type parameter, does it give you the location you want? What does NSLog say the string is?

Comment: If I remove it and If I leave the type parameter, it does give me the location I want. It launches in apple maps, but the maptype isn't set to satellite or hybrid as desired no matter what, but standard (default).

Comment: If it's like googlemaps, you might be able to use `t=k` (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9919251/264775)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Map is display with the graphical map type. You can change the map type to satellite by appending **`‘&t=k’`**,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=%@,%@&t=k", LatitudeCurrentLocation, LongitudeCurrentLocation]]];
```

For more information read [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon) and also [This Documentation.](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-quick-tip-launching-maps-in-app/)

Comment: More info is available on Apple Documentationhttps://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html may be it is helpful for someone else