# Open TextBox value (address) in google maps by clicking button using c#

Tags: c#, google-maps, textbox

I got a question:
I'm writing a short program, which the user is typing in his/her name, age and adsress. after that, the user will click the "Load Data" button i created. then their address etc. will be listed in a new form. and now i got a "Google Maps" button. so when they click the "google maps" button, it should open their browser on google maps and pointing at the address they typed in. someone got an idea?

cheers

Answer (score 1):

The current structure for Google Maps urls is ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9919251/51)):

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?t=m&q=Location
```

So in order to do this, you would want to (assuming that you are using ASP.net):

1. On a click event for the GoogleMaps button, concatenate the address fields together
2. Use this structure to create a maps url using this in the `q` parameter (be sure to Html Encode)
3. `Response.Redirect(googleMapsUrl);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will have a look at it and after I will tell you more :)

Comment: Your solution won't help me :/ But I try it with Google Maps API v3 now. Thank you for your try to help me :)