# How do I specify a marker in a url using a name and lat/long for the new Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I tried generating a url as per the answer by Everton Cunha here: [What parameters should I use in a Google Maps URL to go to a lat-lon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon) i.e.

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=MY%20LOCATION@lat,long
```

This works for me in Google Maps in what is now called "Classic Mode", but in the new Google Maps, it places a marker, displays the lat/long next to it, and the marker does not display any information when I click on it, and the nearest address appears in the search box. I need a url that places the marker at the specified lat/long, and also includes some text describing what the marker is.