# New Google Maps: URL with marker and name

Tags: google-maps

What URL do you need, to show a **name** on the marker with the new Google Maps?

This used to work

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=Name+of+place@32.5234,-78.23432
```

But it's not showing the name anymore on the new Google Maps

<sup>[Similar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46814/how-to-show-a-marker-with-a-description-at-specific-coordinates-via-url-with-the) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434820/how-do-i-specify-a-marker-in-a-url-using-a-name-and-lat-long-for-the-new-google?rq=1) have been asked last year but no answer.</sup>