# How to get the MID of a location in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to add the map in my wordpress site, but i have to put only the characters after ‘mid=’
Example:

-https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?msa=0&mid=zYSGCTGPw92M.kZ0t92LPNDTM the url of the address;

- mid=zYSGCTGPw92M.kZ0t92LPNDTM the part of the url i need to see;
- zYSGCTGPw92M.kZ0t92LPNDTM the code to put in google maps source field.

The problem is that now, whatever address i put in search field of google map, that MID does not change! So in the end i get to have the previous address again. 
Can anyone give me a hint, how does google maps work now?? How do i get that mid to change?

Thanks all,
Best regards!

Answer (score 8):

To anyone that may get lost like i did, here is the answer -> http://support.themeple.co/Faq_quare/google-maps-element-the-right-url/

The procedure to create embed maps to insert in the theme:

Example Address:
3740 Dacoro Lane
Castle Rock, CO 80109 -

The right url: https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=z3hN7mkYycnw.kUH548HocdUw

The code needed for '**Google Maps**' element of the theme: *z3hN7mkYycnw.kUH548HocdUw*

How to get it:

```
1- Go to https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/ (My Maps)


2- Add New Map 


3-In the search field, type your address 


4- In the box shown above the pointer, click Add to Map 


5- In the top left box, click on 'Untitled Map' and set a name for the new created map. 


6- Link to share  


7- Give permission to be viewed by everyone on web 


8-Copy link and share! 


9- Go back to https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/ (My Maps) - Open Map  


10- Select your address from the list (check box)


11- Copy the code (after mid=) in the url bar!


12-Paste this code to your Google Maps element;
```

..and it's done!

Best regards!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @laalto thank you for your suggestion, i did not know, my answer was not in the most correct form. But by deleting my answer, you also removed the opportunity for others to see it and get a solution. The link is still active so no one would have had any problem accesing it! Next time, please limit to just giving an advice.Thank you for your undersanding.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon) for information on URL parameters. I'm not sure what you need the MID for, but it sounds like MID might be a Map ID (just guessing), which does not change even if make a new search. If you want to search via your URL try `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=LOCATION` instead.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had already found the solution. I gave an aswer to my question, but someone deleted it due to bad formation. I undeleted and edited it again. I hope others can see the solution now and profit from it like i did. Best regards!