# Google map zoom parameter in url not working

Tags: google-maps, zooming

Why doesn't google map z (zoom) parameter work inside the url?
I' ve searched over so I got few solutions for sending zoom parameter in google map url but based on the old posts (stackoverflow) which deal with the zoom level within the url it seems that this functionalities do not work anymore.

I've used the following z parameter but it's not working:

http://maps.google.com/?q=38.6531004,-90.243462&z=12

Below is the link where they have mentioned z parameter for zoom level
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

For those who do not want to read, 
this works (**z range**:[1-20]):

https://maps.google.com/?q=38.6531004,-90.243462&ll=38.6531004,-90.243462&z=3

There is **no documentation** that covers this problem. However, there are few hacks.

The link that you have provided,

URL (stackoverflow):[What parameters should I use in a Google Maps URL to go to a lat-lon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon)

Will not help you with getting the desired **google maps zoom level inside a url**

The following examples which have been working for quite a while **DO NOT WORK** anymore (they work but without getting the desired zoom level)

Examples:

- http://maps.google.com/?q=38.6531004,-90.243462&z=3
- http://maps.google.com/?q=38.6531004,-90.243462&zoom=3
- http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Scottish+Rite+Hamilton+ON&loc:43.25911+-79.879494&z=15

Instead, you can get the zoom level easily by trying the following examples:

- https://www.google.com/maps/@38.6531004,-90.243462,9z
- https://maps.google.com/?ll=40.7060471,-74.0088901&z=3

(Note: after clicking on google maps you will get a gray marker which appears and quickly disappears)

However the above URL's will not give you a static pinpoint for the specified lat&long.

There is a "hack" on how to get a **fixed pinpoint** (red marker pin) and that is by giving the **q** attribute (represents the search query) and the **II** attribute(latitude and longitude of the map centre point) along with the **z** (zoom attribute)

Example (with the OP coordinates):

https://maps.google.com/?q=38.6531004,-90.243462&ll=38.6531004,-90.243462&z=3

If you want to change the zoom level just change the value of 'z'.

After searching the web I found that only this website:
https://moz.com/blog/new-google-maps-url-parameters
deals with google maps parameters/attributes/arguments, where things actually still work. If anyone want's more functionalities within the url, then this is the site to check.

**Zoom intervals explained (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Zoomlevels):**

> The following list shows the approximate level of detail you can
>   expect to see at each zoom level:
>
> - 1: World
> - 5: Landmass/continent
> - 10: City
> - 15: Streets
> - 20: Buildings

Comment: its working  by trying above link but it doesn't point the pin(red marker pin) now.

Comment: Sadly you need lat,ong

Comment: @JamieHutber did you perhaps find a better approach in 2017? As I can see things still haven't change..

Comment: Nope, looking around its very much based upon the `@long,lat,Xz` so without the lat and long you won't get very far. I played around a lot with the idea of `place` ie `'https://www.google.com/maps/place/'+address.replace(/ /ig, '+') + '+'+postcode.replace(/ /ig, '+')+'/@11z'` Still no luck I'm afraid.

Comment: @cytsunny 1.5 years have passed and no update from google, unbelievable

Comment: using http://maps.google.com/?q=<lat>,<lng> will add marker but sadly we can't use zoom parameter

Answer (score 19):

This works as of 5 Aug 2018

`http://www.google.com/maps/place/<lat>,<lng>/@<lat>,<lng>,<zoom>z`

For example
http://www.google.com/maps/place/49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796/@49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796,7z

Comment: This still works as of March 2023.

Answer (score 1):

As of 04/2020 ...."because google is always changing and evolving"

In complement to **Eugen Sunic** comments above, and an alternative update to the Solution.

When Logged in to google and getting map data from the google generator, it is not the same as copying the URL from the browser window (which my may be manipulated to load different zooms trough the various alterations, html, Css and script tricks).

But in the below, keep in mind that Your address info may need to be part of the google array of database, eg you have some address map info linked to your account, images, business name, etc. or not... maybe just typed in for a quick map search with a pin-point... the later I don't know.

Also the below is not some Google API pay per 1k clicks thing, which is more geared to the commercial development end of google tracking heat maps, etc. So if you just need a simple solution and certain zoom and marker to work..then you might try the below.

When logged in too your Google account (maybe not) and showing your location marker on the map screen...

Choose the zoom detail of the map you want to appear in your web page. eg Whole US, State views, City, Street (by clicking the + or - zoom feature).

Then go to the hamburger menu to the left, and look down the list for **"Share or Embed Map"** and the popup window should load the same zoom level of the map! Do not try to change the zoom in the popup window feature, it wont work to change the link code but will change the pop up windows zoom of the map. In short, the embedded link code is preset and will not change in the popup.

Above this popup window of the map there will be two options at the top (**Share**  and **Embed**) button/link selections.

Click on the **Embed** link/button and it should generate the code for the zoom you previously chose.

Lastly, copy the code, paste it into your web page and TEST!

As far as I can tell, There is no altering this code as the others suggested above, changing(z=3, 9z, etc) as the code is entirely different. But it will allow you to get the zoom you need "if the google code generator or procedure does not change".

But the zoom level was altered and good enough for me when I figured the process out. Changing it to other zooms is another can of code.

Comment: So in your solution one cannot change the coordinates or zoom level?