# Google Maps Url, Zoom parameter not working

Tags: google-maps

I have this link that works:
https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=map&query=1547+21st+Ave%2C+San+Francisco%2C+CA+94122&basemap=satellite

When i try to add "&Zoom=20", i get a black screen.  Anyone know how to fix this?

https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=map&query=1547+21st+Ave%2C+San+Francisco%2C+CA+94122&basemap=satellite&zoom=21

Comment: It's easy to get confused with the documentation, as all the options are listed on a single page, but when displaying a map with a marker there is no zoom parameter available.  That parameter is only available when displaying a map without a marker.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to use incompatible parameters.

From the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Under "Display a map" (Note it specifies no markers or directions):

map_action=map is required and does not have "query" listed under parameters. One thing that is available is "center" and using the coordinates from the address you provided we get this:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=map&center=37.7588375,-122.481441&basemap=satellite&zoom=21
```

Now if this is not what you are looking for then there are other threads that discuss this like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806084) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201).

And you will get something like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?z=20&t=k&q=1547+21st+Ave%2C+San+Francisco%2C+CA+94122
```

This will give you a satellite view map with a marker on the location specified.

Comment: Note, the z parameter in your last example also does not work.  It does not change the zoom, no matter what value you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

Today (2023-08-15) the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50635690/4145280) doesn't work for me.
But
http://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.7588437,-122.4792782&z=21&t=k&q=1547+21st+Ave,+San+Francisco,+CA+94122
does

- The 'll' parameter sets the center of the map and seems mandatory for z to work (btw: even upper 20, but with poor quality)
- The 'q' parameter gives the marker and the text in tooltip and search field (which can be out of sight if far from the center of map)

Comment: by "upper 20", did you mean above 20?

Comment: Yes, 21 and even more are accepted but are useless