# How to change google mymaps iframe embed zoom?

Tags: google-maps, parameters, mymaps

I've got an embedded google mymaps. It seems the zoom parameter doesn't work at all. I cannot find any useful information on google documentation.

Mymaps seem not to follow the standard iframe maps api.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1gatxEY51NXkSRl461HgAxmk2bwI" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

EDIT:

Following Matej's accepted answer, I found a couple of useful links:

[What parameters should I use in a Google Maps URL to go to a lat-lon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon)

https://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

And then modified my embed code like this, so I could add zooming (through 'z' param) and centering (through 'll' param):

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1gatxEY51NXkSRl461HgAxmk2bwI&z=5&ll=43.7695600,11.2558140" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

And by the way: I usually like to find my  lat/lng position with this site:

http://mygeoposition.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try add `z=nn` parameter to the url where `nn` is the zoom level.

This works for me:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1gatxEY51NXkSRl461HgAxmk2bwI&z=10" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add zoom=nn parameter to the url where nn is the zoom level.
This is how I solved the issue.