# Automating extraction of latitude, longitude and other information about places from Google

Tags: r, geolocation, web-crawler, rvest, httr

If you type https://www.google.ca/maps/search/Southern+Saskatchewan in your internet browser,
Google will conveniently (and automatically!) redirect you to:
https://www.google.ca/maps/search/Southern+Saskatchewan/@54.1966035,-115.5094433,5z/data=!3m1!4b1

From there you can see and manually copy and paste the latitude (47.0159646), longitude (-65.6188287) and some other information (5z/data=!3m1!4b1 - I'm not sure what it is) about this region (Southern Saskatchewan).

Is there a way to automate this process somehow - so that such information can be retrieved with R function  `retrievePlaceInfoFromGoogle <- function(strPlaceName)`  ?

Maybe with httr or rvest or any any web technology package?

Comment: Btw, does anyone know what this other info after the geo location (5z/data=!3m1!4b1) is?

Comment: Found this related link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon/44859423

Answer (score 2):

Any attempt to use Google other than the "official" way is going to be blocked and you will get the "unusual traffic detected notification" and tested if you are a human by choosing traffic lights for example.
The official way for geocoding is through the google API. Once you have an api key you could use the `googleway` package for example:

```
require(googleway)
set_key("your_google_key_of_39_characters")
x= google_geocode(address = "Southern Saskatchewan", simplify = TRUE)
x$results$geometry
```

Comment: There are also alternatives to Google. For example:`tidygeocoder::geo_osm('Southern Saskatchewan')`