# How to create a Google Maps link to a pin at given GPS coordinates and also a forced pin info text?

Tags: google-maps, url

Based on [What parameters should I use in a Google Maps URL to go to a lat-lon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon) , I've tried the following:

- https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Place+de+la+R%C3%A9publique,+Paris,+France/@48.867598,2.3630041,18z
  [image: ignores info text, redirects to Pl. de la République object of interest and changes coords]
- https://maps.google.com/?q=Place+de+la+R%C3%A9publique,+Paris,+France@48.867598,2.3630041
  [image: ignores info text, shows gps coords instead]
- https://maps.google.com/?q=Place+de+la+R%C3%A9publique,+Paris,+France&ll=48.867598,2.3630041
- https://maps.google.com/?q=48.867598,2.3630041(Place+de+la+R%C3%A9publique,+Paris,+France)

But none of them will make a pin with this given text, at best it retrieves the nearest object of interest. Is there a way to link a pin at exact coordinates and force a given label text (will be an address or business name, but I'd like to link exact coordinates and ensure that the displayed info text exactly matches what I specify in the URL)?

Thanks!

Comment: Everything that you can do is [documented](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't ask Google Maps to display a custo infotext / label but if you want Maps to display the official label, you need to form your URL like so

https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=Place+de+la+R%C3%A9publique,+Paris

The documentation that @MrUpsidown has linked is the right one.